# Why cannot Mongodb connect?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, server, port, database

I'm trying to connect MongoDB on my Mac OSx, and I installed using homebrew.  In one terminal window, I set up the database with `mongod` command, and at the end of the reply, it says, as expect

```
waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Then, I open up another terminal window, and type `mongo` to get to the mongo shell.

However, the first terminal window does NOT acknowledge my connection it seems like.  I suspect it could be from a bad shutdown.  This answer has some info:
[Why won't my mongodb connect to port 28017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758068/why-wont-my-mongodb-connect-to-port-28017)
But it doesn't help me to change the port number.

Firstly, how do I do a clean shutdown?  The tutorial here [from the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) says to use `Control+C`, which is what I used to shutdown.
Secondly, how do I change the port number that mongo connects to mongodb server?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "the first terminal window does NOT acknowledge my connection"? Can you make queries from the second terminal? The mongod terminal usually does not report connections, btw.

Comment: In the tutorials I've seen, (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uFY60CESlM at ~12:20), it will print "connection now open" when it connects.  \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From first terminal

```
./mongod --port 27017
```

From another one

```
./mongo --port 27017
```

Assuming in both terminals you are in mongo executable directory. Change the ports as u wish. Also ctrl+C is not the issue, I always use that to shut down.